# Differential equation - variable substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have done very little on this problem. Sorry if I don't have even begun a solution. The reason is that I am unsure how to do it.

Here's a differential equation:
$$
(y'')^3sin(y')+cos(xy')=tan((y')^4)
$$

The question is : Which variable substitution would you do to bring this to a differential equation of order 1?

The answer is : p(x) = y'

Considering I'm not supposed to use trigonometric identities, I have difficulty seeing how I can achieve it (but it's ok if you use one... willing to take any solution)

I mean...
it would give

$$
(p')^3sin(p) + cos(xp)= tan(p^4)
$$

I still don't get it.

How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(p')^3 \sin(p) + \cos(xp)= \tan(p^4)$$

This gives us:

$$p' = \left(\dfrac{\tan(p^4) - \cos(xp)}{\sin(p)}\right)^{1/3}$$

It is now a first-order, non-linear equation.

Can you see how to proceed now?

Comment: Yes, you mean there's only p' and p. But still, I get you, but... from that point... how would you solve the equation? By using euler's equations maybe? Using tan(x) = sin(x)/cos(x)?

Comment: I do not think they intended for you to solve it, if I read the question properly. Just to make a substitution to convert from second to first order.

Comment: I'm still curious. Would it even be possible to solve this? :)